# Triangulation of an object with measurements in a line

Tags: math, trigonometry, triangulation

is there any way to triangulate the position of an object if I have the distance to the object from three points without direction that are in a line?

that is I have the points (0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,2,0) and point x that is 1.7,1.3, 1.7 away from the respective measuring points.

Is there a way to eliminate the ghost point if you are limited to straight line measurements?

Kind regards and appreciation for any assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by "straight line measurements"? Do you want an algorithm to compute the coordinate of the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can measure the distances from the object to as many points on the line as you like; if you mirror-reflect the object across the line, the new object will have all the same distances as the old one. To distinguish these two points you must take some kind of measurement that is *not* mirror-symmetric across the line (which distance to any point on the line is).